# Wpf data visualisation

Tags: wpf, silverlight, charts

I'm using data visualisation libary and I want to do something like in the attached image:

[image]

two kinds of bars one on each other, How can I do that ?

Comment: Is this Silverlight or WPF or both?

Comment: Are you using a specific library already? Or you'd use any component that lets you do this?

Comment: @Gergely Orosz - I'm using Data Visualisation, it's microsoft free library

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Visiblox Charts](http://visiblox.com) offers a MultiValueSeriesBase in their free version. Extending this should be able to implement something like your chart above.

Answer (score 0):

[Dynamic Data Display](http://dynamicdatadisplay.codeplex.com/) is a free library for WPF on CodePlex which can do graphing.

Infragistics offers a [WPF Data Visualization](http://www.infragistics.com/dotnet/netadvantage/wpf/data-visualization.aspx) library. [xamChart](http://www.infragistics.com/dotnet/netadvantage/wpf/data-visualization/xam-chart.aspx) would do what you're looking for. Currently it's $995 without support.

Comment: 10x third party libraries are unpermitted in my project, only skd's of Microsoft